# Updating questions after they've been answered to give a follow-up

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently asked a programming [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582189/url-in-string-being-corrupted-with-apostrophe) about an unusual problem I was having where browsers were inserting apostrophes into URLs that were displayed as raw HTML.

An answer was provided and as a result I was able to come up with a workaround to solve the problem. The answer itself was very helpful (and I accepted it) but didn't give a detailed solution so I decided to provide an update to the question text stating specifically what I did to solve the problem.

My question is: *What's the preferred way of handling this?*

Updating the question with how I solved the problem seems a clunky way of doing things: You see the question, there's an answer in the question text and then the accepted answer is further down.

I had thought of providing another answer as an update but this didn't feel right either. Editing the accepted answer to include my final solution seems quite a radical change to make. How should I have approached this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't update the question with the solution.

If you have a more detailed solution than was provided by the other answers then post it as your own answer - referencing the other answers that helped you as well as upvoting them. This is what Stack Overflow is designed for.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the question to remove the update and added it as an answer.